# Showing error isDisplayed() and .text() navigator error after upgrading Geb to 1.0 from 0.10.0 and selenium to 3.0.1

Tags: selenium, groovy, spock, geb

I was trying to upgrade Geb and Selenium version in build.gradle. After updating version geb 0.10.0 to geb 1.0 and Selenium 2.47.1 to 3.0.1 giving error as .isDisplayed and text() methods navigator error. I am using groovy 2.4.3. I am using spockframeork:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.4

Answer (score 0):

Do not use selenium 3.0.1, you should use 2.52.0 version see documentation for Geb 1.0: http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/#gradle

What exactly error do you see? Could you give us a stacktrace or something.